# How to change the way my requests.get() function is sent?

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-requests

I am trying to create an http request to get some json data from a site online. When I set up the requests.get() function, it seems to be translating some of the special characters in the parameters to other values, causing the response to fail. Is there a way to control how the .get() is sent?

I'm trying to send this http request:
['https://registers.esma.europa.eu/solr/esma_registers_firds_files/select?q=*&fq=publication_date:%5B2020-05-10T00:00:00Z+TO+2020-05-10T23:59:59Z%5D&wt=json&indent=true&start=0&rows=100'](http://'https://registers.esma.europa.eu/solr/esma_registers_firds_files/select?q=*&fq=publication_date:%5B2020-05-10T00:00:00Z%20TO%202020-05-10T23:59:59Z%5D&wt=json&indent=true&start=0&rows=100')

To do so, here is my code:

```
response = requests.get('https://registers.esma.europa.eu/solr/esma_registers_firds_files/select',
                   params={'q':'*',
                          'fq':'publication_date:%5B2020-05-10T00:00:00Z+TO+2020-05-10T23:59:59Z%5D',
                          'wt':'json',
                          'indent': 'true',
                          'start':0,
                          'rows':100},)
```

However, this code seems to translate the '*' character and the ':' character into a different format, which means I'm getting a bad response code. Here is how it prints out when I run the .url() on the code:

```
response.url
```

> > https://registers.esma.europa.eu/solr/esma_registers_firds_files/select?q=%2A&fq=publication_date%3A%255B2020-05-10T00%3A00%3A00Z%2BTO%2B2020-05-10T23%3A59%3A59Z%255D&wt=json&indent=true&start=0&rows=100

You can see that the '*' in the 'q' param became '%2A', and the ':' in the 'fq' param became '%3A', etc.

I know the link works, because if I enter it directly into the requests.get(), I get the results I expect.

Is there a way to make it so that the special characters in the .get() don't change? I've been googling anything related to the requests module and character encoding, but haven't had any luck. I could just use the whole url each time I need it, but I think that using params is better practice. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not actually the problem. The conversion you're seeing is **supposed** to happen. It's called URL encoding.

The problem is in the `publication_date` value. See the `%5B` and `%5D` and the `+` signs?

```
'fq':'publication_date:%5B2020-05-10T00:00:00Z+TO+2020-05-10T23:59:59Z%5D'
                       ^^^                    ^  ^                    ^^^
```

I don't know where you got this string, but this string has already gone through URL encoding. The `%5B`, `%5D`, and `+` are encoded forms of `[`, `]`, and space. You need to provide unencoded values, like this:

```
'fq':'publication_date:[2020-05-10T00:00:00Z TO 2020-05-10T23:59:59Z]'
```

`requests` will handle the encoding.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help! I was looking at that for ages. Appreciate your help!